# Sum of a metric from distinct users in Google Analytics/Looker Studio

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, looker-studio

I am sending a GA event on every login with the user score. The event looks like the following:

```
{
  "app_instance_id":"2a787c8629b984d9343e68e",
  "user_id":"38293294",
  "events":[
    {
      "name":"login",
      "params":{
        "user_score":1700
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted to calculate the total score of all the users in a Looker Studio report. I created a custom metric for `user_score`. The problem I am facing is that the sum of user scores also includes scores from the same user if they log in multiple times, whereas I want the sum of scores from distinct users with unique `user_id`.

How can I aggregate the users and compute the sum of scores in Looker Studio? Any possible solution would be really appreciated.